# Photoshop icon missing after deleting desktop shortcut in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, shortcuts, desktop-icons

I deleted a bunch of shortcut icons on the desktop in Windows 7 to clear the screen. One of them was Photoshop cs5. Ever since its icon has gone missing. I get the default icon for unknown app in the start menu. The properties dialog for the PS shows the correct PS icon and the path. I've tried changing the icon, rebuilding the icon cache by deleting Icon cache database, re-adding the desktop shortcut. Nothing works. How can I fix this?

Comment: I get this problem from time to time with Acrobat and it's very annoying. It changes the icon to that of Windows Photo Viewer with two arrows on the icon. Usually you have to fix it by going to the location of the actual EXE and then copying and pasting it as a shortcut in the Start menu (replacing the old shortcut).

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 things you can try.

Open the folder `"C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop CS5"`, or `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop CS5"` if you have a 64-bit installation of windows.

Inside there, you should see a program named `photoshop.exe`. Right click it, point to `Send to`, and click `Send the desktop (create shortcut)`.
If it still doesn't work, or if you cannot find the above, uninstall then reinstall Photoshop and your problem should fix itself.

Comment: Yeah I tried that too. The shortcut is created with the proper icon but the start menu and running application still show no icon for PS.

Comment: @koogee - When you install photoshop, select custom install. Make sure that "put shortcut in start menu" is ticked.

Comment: Use this link http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/135246-start-menu-all-programs-windows-7-restore-default-shortcuts.html

Comment: @koogee Try adding the shortcut to the Start menu as well.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit old but I had the same problem and I managed to fix it much easier. I right clicked on the premiere pro (or photoshop or whatever, it happened with premiere with me), click properties, then icon change (or something like this, my computer isnt in english idk what its called in english but basically the butt with which you change the icon), chose a random icon, click use and then ok, then go back to properties and change icon and change it to the original icon, for me it was the first icon, and there were other similar adobe icons provided by adobe by default. Its important to click ok and close the window before otherwise it wont work.